# Number of certain type of words

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the number of words consists of two letters $s$ and $t$ of size $k$ that contain exactly three letters $t$ and no adjacent two letters $t$?

Comment: The *words* you meant with no other constraints?

Comment: @Niing: for instance, if k=5 here's an example tstst.

Comment: Hint.  Lay out $k-3$ `s`'s.  Now... pick where to slide the `t`'s into the arrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps can be

$$(\textrm{Fix three t's})\cdot(\textrm{Insert two s' between t})\cdot(\textrm{other works}),$$

and to the *other works* is distributing indistinguishable items into distinguishable places, so

$$1\cdot1\cdot\binom{(k-3-2)+3}{3},$$

which $(k-3-2)$ is the remaining number of $s$, and with three bars to separate them into four places separated by three $t$'s. E.g.

$$\color{blue}{OO}|||\color{blue}{OO}\to \color{blue}{ss}\ t\ s\ t\ s\ t\ \color{blue}{ss},\\
O|\color{red}{O}||OO\to s\ t\ \color{red}{s}s\ t\ s\ t\ ss.$$